# Regex to remove unwanted spaces around certain characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to remove some unwanted whitespace from JavaScript files, and combine files using C# and Regex, before they are sent to the client. I have a `JavascriptHandler` to handle the .js files, which works fine. This is the function that I'm using to "pack" the JavaScript.

```
private string PackJs(string file)
{
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(JSFolder + file);

    //replace any combination of unwanted whitespace with a single space
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[\r\n\s]+", " ");

    //Can I get this to match +, =, -, etc?
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"( [=] )", "="); 

    //more regular expressions here, when I get round to it

    return text;
}
```

My second expression currently will replace " = " with "=". I'd like to specify more characters and keywords that can have the spaces removed from either side.

How do I search for this in the regular expression, then back-reference that character or keyword in the replacement?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that you want to replace `\r+` or `\n+` with plain spaces? I'm fairly sure that could potentially change the semantics of your JavaScript (even if it doesn't break the syntax).

Comment: Is the js "know well formed? "`a=1\r\nb=4` & `a=1;b=4` are ok `a=1 b=4` is not

Comment: Yes, I put semi colons after every statement in my JS. I can edit the JS anyway, I'm only trying to make it readable for me to change, and have it nicely packed when it's sent to the client.

Comment: Tip: A free very helpful tool is the rad software regular expression designer: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/?from=RegexDesigner

Comment: If you have gzip compression enabled in your webserver then this (and more) will all be done for you on-the-fly anyway. No need to manually trim superfluous spaces.

Comment: @SACO, your link to the RegexDesigner appears to be broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `[]` put your characters

```
var input = "c = a + b";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s([=+])\s", "$1");
```

Result would be: `c=a+b`

Comment: I knew it would be something. My understanding of the $1 was wrong. I thought you had to specify which statement will be the return value for $1 somehow in your regex string. Working now. Basically.. my `()` backets were in the wrong place.

Comment: you should use `\s*` instead of just `\s`

Answer (score 1):

to remove whitespace around some characters like `[=*/+-]` use this regex:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s*([=*/+-])\s*", "$1");
```

between `[]` the `-` character must be the first or the last to avoid it's meaning of a range of chracters

[test code example](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=1e8db7c2)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you reinventing the wheel?
Check http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/ out.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @(" (=|\+|-) ", "$1");
```